# Why JsonSanitizer is not working for Json Injection?

Tags: java, security, owasp, fortify, application-security

Security tool is complaining JsonInjection when deserializing the json string into java model. My application have been using jackson to do serialization/deserialization. I read jackson does default escaping things and all and referenced internet stuffs to fix this issue.

As I got to know that, there were two options for handling with this issue.

1. Schema validation - It says that, json needs to be validated against schema and input fields needs to be validated against patterns, etc before deserialization happens.
2. Use JsonSanitizer - Sanitize the json string to well formed json.

We went with option 2. Because, our application cannot validate the json against schema since more than 200 API's in the application.

JsonSanitizer does not help us. I am writing the piece of code to show you what we tried to fix this issue.

Our application uses this method for all API's and cannot perform schema validation.

Is there anyother solution to get rid of JsonInjection issue?

````
public <T> T jsonToBean(Class<T> cls, String json) {
        try {
            String sanitizedJson = json;
            if (json.trim().startsWith("{") || json.trim().startsWith("[")) {
                sanitizedJson = com.google.json.JsonSanitizer.sanitize(json);
            }
            return objectMapper.readValue(sanitizedJson, cls);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Deserialization fails");
        }
        return null;
    }```
````

Comment: Please provide more details on what exactly this "JsonInjection". How is this injection is supposed to work and what consequences are noted in this security tools? If it does not provide more details the tool is useless. Also make sure that the finding is not a false-positive.

Comment: Security tools provides the scenario of json injection while serializing it. Please refer this link https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/detail?id=desc.dataflow.java.json_injection.. The explaination given in this link is available in the issue but in my case it is deserialization.

Comment: The described attack only works in case you process the incoming data as `JsonNode`. But I assume you are convert/deserialize them to bean classes. In this case the class is your schema which is automatically validated when you convert/deserialize it (fields in JSON that don't have a field/setter in the class result in an error unless you configured it to ignore it).

Comment: I completely agree with you. But, when a injection is made in a json field, application cannot validate at the field level. For example, json field "password" : "evil123!<iframe option". I cannot implement a validation/pattern or rules for each field in my bean class.

Comment: "`evil123!<iframe option`" is a totally valid password and have to be accepted. If it triggers a vulnerability in your application then it is the fault of the application (missing html escaping) but not of the JSON deserializer.